# Should a user lose her reputation from a closed question?

Tags: discussion

As it is mentioned numerous times, there are question on Stack Overflow that are there just for historical reason, showing "What we should not do/ask". Most of these questions are closed as `off-topic`, `not constructive`, `too broad`, etc. In addition, most of these questions show minimal to no effort.

The argument/question here is: Why should the user retain the reputation and (maybe) the badges earned for this question?

Another issue which again was discussed many times is that this type of questions is a bad example for new users. Having or showing the positive votes on closed question may be mislead the new users, thinking that this question is great, even if it is closed.

Comment: Why the obsession with denying people rep? The bad example point is already covered by the big yellow box that says "DONT POST STUFF LIKE THIS YOU HAVE BEEN WARNED"

Comment: @Magisch When you see someone has gotten thousands of rep from an off topic/low quality closed post, it is disconcerting if you are trying to gain rep. Fairness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why should the user retain the reputation and (maybe) the badges earned for this question.

Because enough users thought their post was helpful, and that is enough reason for it. We don't scrutinize user's voting choices as long as it's not serial or sock puppetry.

> In addition most of this questions show minimal to none effort.

If they are highly upvoted, obviously a lot of people disagree with you on that.

> Another issue which again discussed many times is that these types of questions are a bad example for new user.

That's exactly why we have the big yellow box telling new users not to post stuff like that. We expect new users to be able to read.

Comment: _"enough users thought their post was helpful"_ - that is not _at all_ how most users use their upvotes.

Comment: @CodeCaster thats what they're supposed to be used as, though.

Comment: Yup, but they aren't. They're used more as "likes", which is no indication whatsoever of quality.

Answer (score 7):

> Why should the user retain the reputation and (maybe) the badges earned for this question.

We (as a community) have changed our views over time about what kind of questions are acceptable.

That shouldn't mean that we retrospectively punish users for posting a question that was acceptable **at the time it was originally posted**.

Comment: But what about new questions that are closed as off topic that gain rep?

Comment: The question is about "question on Stack Overflow that are there just for historical reason" not about new questions.

Comment: It's about gaining rep from closed questions. If I were to post my own question, it would have the exact same question title.